# Use a PHP variable to dynamically display an image in HTML

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use a variable in a .php file to choose img src.
Here's my attempt:

`<?php echo "<img src=\"$ICON\">"; ?>`
or
 `<img src="<?php echo $ICON; ?>"/>`

Neither have worked, is there anything obviously wrong? There's nothing displaying, not even the code, when I render the page.

Any guidance would be much appreciated, especially a correct implementation of the above. Sorry for poor code, only looked at these languages since yesterday.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with both pieces of code. The value of the variable is unknown, as is what results HTML source actually reveals.

Comment: if the variable doesn't contain the image path you need to add it

Comment: Maybe silly questions, but: how do you call the script? Do you have 'http://localhost....' or 'http://127.0.0.1/....' or 'file://...' in your browser's address?

Comment: @عارفبنالأزرق I echoed the image path before hand and it was correct, though it still wouldn't display

Comment: @Funky Forty Niner I echoed the image path before hand and it was correct, though it still wouldn't display

Comment: @Jeff I have a localhost:8000 address, the server was set up with 
`php -S localhost:8000`

EDIT: The script was then loaded by opening the .php file within the same directory the command was run in. Visual elements, and even other php elements, run correctly.

Comment: Does the img tag work if you put the exact same path in it as text instead of a variable?  The answer we'd expect is: no, it does not.  If $ICON is not empty, then it is not a valid URL.  Fix the value given to $ICON and this should work.  Also, please read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve] then edit your question to be a proper MCVE.

Comment: @DaveS It turns out that it does not, it hadn't occurred to me to check (stupidly). Have you any ideas what may cause that? The image is openable and findable via the path

Comment: again we would need the actual value of `$ICON` to be able to _guess_.

Comment: Sorry, `$ICON` holds a path to the image, the path looks like `/home/pi/Dashboard/observation_Icons/nt_mostlycloudy.png`. The `php -S localhost:8000` command was run in `/home/pi/Dashboard/`.

Comment: make `$ICON='observation_Icons/nt_mostlycloudy.png'` and test. The path is either relative to the active script or absolute to public root path (with `/` at the start)

Comment: @Jeff That worked! Thank you. Have you a reckon why a relative path works when an absolute path does not?

Comment: an absolute path starts with a `www.site.com/` or `C:/`. That was a relative path, but from the wrong directory

Comment: @ezw It's a Unix path, no path started with C:/ drive so the root directory is '/'. Though I take the point of www.site.com/.